# Jenkins Error starting static Resources

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jenkins

Read almost all links under the title (when creating topic) and more of them in google, did not find the answer.
So, the problem is: jenkins builds maven web project. I installed the Deploy plugin, so that jenkins would publish .WAR file to tomcat.
Tests section passed and WAR file is built - OK, but when jenkins starts to

```
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:run (default-cli) @ webapp ---
```

I see:

```
ERROR] Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/AppFolder/AppName/src/main/webapp does not exist or is not a readable directory
```

And if I look to the project's folder, there really is no such folder, because it is:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/AppFolder/AppName/src/com/companyname/webapp
```

so, I just don't know where to fix the path. Tried to edit pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/com/companyname</sourceDirectory>
    ...
</build>
```

Just don't get it. Where that path is specified?

Comment: Upd: ugh, how did I forget about effective pom.xml. Will try to see what settings are in there and try to change them.

Comment: Upd: nope, seems like that was not the case. added
<resources>
 <resource>
  <directory>src/com/companyname/resources</directory>
 </resource>
</resources> but it didn't help in jenkins, same paths, same error

Comment: Would it be possible to post your POM?

Comment: Yes, there you go: http://pastebin.com/VsL6krZn Now I have another problem: in Jenkins war is built but everything hangs at 
[INFO] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8087"]
[INFO] Starting service Tomcat
[INFO] Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
[INFO] No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
[INFO] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8087"]
now it hangs forever.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I made errors in configuration.

```
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration> ... <configuration>
```

Now everything works. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this email](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201202.mbox/%3CCAPoyBqSMHzP0zZNjOpTzWkQyUV3Q2R9+=AWecxr+U5XrvZN-sA@mail.gmail.com%3E) might help you. Have a read through it, but from what I can see this is the important part ([Tomcat Maven docs - warSourceDirectory](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-beta-1/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#warSourceDirectory)).

***Quote***:

```
<configuration>
  <warSourceDirectory>target/${artifactId}-${version}</warSourceDirectory>
```

will be better with

```
  <warSourceDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/${artifactId}-${version}</warSourceDirectory>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Unfortunally, that did not help. Made these changes, same error. I can't find anywhere in the project where is that /src/main/. There is no such text anywhere.